# Can't start master and slave, strange thing named "bogon" in the log

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I downloaded a new pre-build spark for hadoop 2.2 file. Following [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/spark-standalone.html#starting-a-cluster-manually) document, I want to launch my master on my single machine. After untar the file, I enter the sbin and start-master, but I face this strange problem, here is the log:

```
Spark Command: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -cp :/opt/spark-0.9.0-incubating-bin-hadoop2/conf:/opt/spark-0.9.0-incubating-bin-hadoop2/assembly/target/scala-2.10/spark-assembly_2.10-0.9.0-incubating-hadoop2.2.0.jar -Dspark.akka.logLifecycleEvents=true -Djava.library.path= -Xms512m -Xmx512m org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --ip bogon --port 7077 --webui-port 8080
========================================

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: bogon/125.211.213.133:7077
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)
    at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:391)
    at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:388)
    at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:206)
```

What's that `bogon`? And where is the IP 125.211.213.133(not my IP) comes from? What's the problem here?

Comment: "bogon" just means "dummy" or "you should replace this with your real value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"bogon" comes from the command line provided. You probably forgot to replace the parameter `--ip` to the local ip of your host.

When using the sbin/start-master.sh, if not IP is provided, the reported hostname of the machine is used:
`start-master.sh`

```
if [ "$SPARK_MASTER_IP" = "" ]; then
  SPARK_MASTER_IP=`hostname`
fi
```

If the reported hostname is not right, you can provide Spark with is IP by setting the env variable.

`SPARK_MASTER_IP=172.17.0.1 start-master.sh`

Comment: @massg Thank you for your help. But I just executed the `start-master.sh`. I didn't type the entire command.

Comment: @hakunami have updated the answer with details on IP address setting.

Answer (score 1):

check your hostname by run the command `hostname` if you are linux env. And I think 125.211.213.133 is the IP for bogon, and you mistakenly set your hostname to "bogon".

For quick fix, you can run command `hostname localhost` and try again.